# How can I stop jquery from running a script once for each class member

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, fadeto

I have the following code:

```
function fadeIn()
    {
    $(".home_photo").fadeTo(1000, 1.0 ).delay(5 * 1000);
    fadeOut();
    }

function doSwap()
    {
    console.log('Swap');
    ... There is some Ajax Code here that swaps the image in the divs ...
    fadeIn();
    }

function fadeOut()
    {
    $(".home_photo").fadeTo(1000, 0.01, doSwap );
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    fadeOut();
});
```

Here is the HTML that goes with it:

```
<body>
<div id="photowrapper">
    <div class="home_photo" id="img1"></div>
    <div class="home_photo" id="img2"></div>
    <div class="home_photo" id="img3"></div>
    <div class="home_photo" id="img4"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

The jQuery script runs one time for each member of the class "home_photo". The problem is that the doSwap function runs 4 times for each swap cycle (fadeOut, doSwap, fadeIn). What do I need to do so that the script will only run once per swap instead of once for each class member?

Comment: `function fadeOut()
    {
    $(".home_photo").fadeTo(1000, 0.01 );
doswap();
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `doSwap()` to run after the `fadeTo()` has completed you could use a jQuery deferred object to control the process:

```
$.when(function() {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    $(".home_photo").fadeTo(1000, 0.01, function(){
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred;

}).then(function(){

    doSwap();

});
```

Comment: You don't have to make your own Deferred or resolve it, as jQuery will make one for you that covers the animation: `$(".home_photo").fadeTo(1000, 0.01).promise().then(doSwap)`.

Comment: @jfriend00, ah! even nicer.